# Applying displacement to complicated face

Tags: modeling

I have a wall with windows, like this:
[image]

I would like to apply a displacement map to the wall. However, this would require some form of subdivision of the face, which would be kind of messy. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: you can fake the displacement with a Normal map or Bump map

Comment: That's the method I'm using right now. I was just curious as to how I would get displacement on a surface like this if I really wanted to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, normal or bump maps plugged into normal or bump nodes don't need any subdivisions, so are you not confusing things? Or please give some precisions...

Comment: I'm talking about displacement maps, the ones which actually modify the geometry of the mesh. I am aware of bump and normal maps.

Comment: I talked about Normal and Bump because it would have been "a more elegant solution", other than Normal, Bump and Displacement I don't know, but again you don't give enough informations, for example what your wall is supposed to look like at the end, why don't Normal, Bump or Displacement fit your needs, etc... ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I am currently using a bump map for the wall, but I was wondering (purely out of curiosity) how I would neatly prepare a mesh like this for displacement. I've since determined that using a boolean modifier for the windows (instead of having them a part of the mesh) makes it easier to subdivide the wall. Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: I don't see any relation between the windows and displacement, you could't not create window with displacement, maybe give more precisions because in my opinion your question is too vague